# How can I know whether a Unicode will be displayed correctly in most user devices?

Tags: android, unicode

I was wondering, is there any way to know, whether a Unicode will be displayed correctly in most user devices?

For instance, I'm using using Unicode `\u26A0`, which is suppose to show a warning sign.

I didn't specify exactly what font to be used in my app. I use the above Unicode in `ListPreference`.

```
alertEmailListPreference.setSummary("(\u26A0 Email address required)");
```

It looks good in my device.

[image]

My only worry is whether such Unicode will be displayed correctly in other devices?

I presume nowadays Android app are using Roboto font by default. However, when I look through http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26a0/fontsupport.htm , I don't find Roboto font is in the list.

How can I know whether the Unicode will be displayed correctly in most user devices?

Comment: `Unicode will be displayed correctly in most user devices` facing same problem